# Logic to remove and add to an array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I get an array by parameter and get the index
and then I splice, but my this.players is still the same.

```
makeMatch(condition) {
  const matchedPlayers = this.players.filter(condition);
  this.removePlayers(matchedPlayers);
  return new Match(matchedPlayers);
}
removePlayers(players) {
  players.forEach(p => {
    this.removePlayer(p);
  });
}
removePlayer(player) {
  const index = this.players.findIndex(p => p.id === player.id);
  console.log(index);
  if (index > -1) {
    this.players.splice(index, -1);
  }
  console.log(this.players);
}
```

after using splice on my index my player collection remains the same

And to remove from the list even after using. slice my list remains the same size

My function to add players to my array

```
// addPlayers add multiple players into queue
addPlayers(players) {
  this.players = this.players.concat(players);
}

// addPlayer adds a single player into queue
addPlayer(player) {
  this.players.push(player);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `-1` as the second argument to `splice`, which should be the number of items to remove (i.e. `1`).

Also, it's possible to simplify `removePlayer` and not use `splice` at all:

```js
removePlayer(player) {
  this.players = this.players.filter(p => p.id !== player.id)
}
```